# problem regarding automation using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

ok. Iam trying to autofill google sign.in page using python and selenium. but, im having two problems.

1. I would like to know if its possible to fill already opened page in the browser instead of opening a new page and filling it.
2. Whenever im trying to fill the page using the code below, it fills the username but then the browser shows a error saying that `couldn't sign in you because the browser or app may not be secure`. How to fix this!!

> ```
> from selenium import webdriver
> import time
> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
> chromedriver = 'd:Drivers\\chromedriver.exe'
> browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
> browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/identifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSession')
> args: ['--disable-web-security', '--user-data-dir', '--allow-running-insecure-content' ]
> username = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]')
> username.send_keys("")
> browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button/div[2]').click()
> time.sleep(3)
> password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
> password.send_keys(" ")
> browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/button/div[2]').click()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting implies that the WebDriver was unable to authenticate the Browsing Context i.e. Browser session.

In these cases, the respective solution would be to:

1. Disable Two Factor Authentification for this Google account and execute your script
2. [Allow less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4NWUeu0lEww7DP1jUZSn5cHXDucIcStxwGjPKfHpeybwNIYYxR_9d14Qm_CjO_xYtfKG1x7CrOAQc0o-Vo1w35nNNzCTg)